# Is there a way to display text as you type in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

Is there a way to display text on screen automatically as you type an input in a text field in Android Studio?

For example, if I type in a number, it gets automatically multiplied by 20 and the result is shown on the screen below the text field.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use on Textview Event listeners to handle your actions!
here is how u can do it.

```
    field1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field2);
    
    field1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {        
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)    
     {     //Called after the changes have been applied to the text.
           //You can change the text in the TextView from this method.

     }  
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
         int count, int after) {
         //Called before the changes have been applied to the text.

       }
    
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
          TextView.setText("Here is the changing text"+s);
     //Similar to the beforeTextChanged method but called after the text changes.
    
    
       }
      });
```

/*
You can prevent an infinite loop like this

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (_ignore)
                return;

            _ignore = true; // prevent infinite loop
            // Change your text here.
            // myTextView.setText(myNewText);
            _ignore = false; // release, so the TextWatcher start to listen again.
        }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the question properly so here is the solution for the 2 different cases.

1. The text to display is in the same Activity or Fragament.
   Use a TextWatcher class like this

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    //This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start have just replaced old text that had length before.
newTextView.text=s.toString; 
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // This method is called to notify you that, within s, the count characters beginning at start are about to be replaced by new text with length after. 
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    // This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed. 
    

    }
});
```

2. The output is in a different screen (fragment/drawer)

You can do it using a combination of TextWatcher and LiveData.
Put a TextWatcher  on your editText and store the data in a Livedata. (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
Then  observe this liveData and change the Textview accordingly.

Comment: don't really see why you would need live data here as you can just change it in the text watcher..